# Classify lexeme of a input String

Tags: haskell

given a String  "3 + a * 6" how do I determine the lexeme one by one? I know that my code is missing `classify xs` part but I don't know where to put it. Can anyone help me with this?
(the language is in Haskell)

```
classify :: String -> String
classify (x:xs)
        |x == '+' = "PLUS"
        |x == '-' = "MINUS"
        |x == '*' = "MULT"
        |x == '/' = "DIV"
        |x == '(' = "LP"
        |x == ')' = "RP"
        |isAlpha x = "VAR"
        |isDigit x = "CONST"
        |otherwise = error "Cannot determine lexeme"
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of tokenisation is best left to lexer generators or parser combinators.  You can try Alex, at http://www.haskell.org/alex/ , or Parsec, at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec .

These tools are designed specifically to make tokenisation/scanning (and parsing, in the case of Parsec) easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only need a tokenizer, here's how you could do it without parsec. I defined an additional ADT for the token types (you can of course convert that back to strings), and  had to change the return type, since you get a sequence of tokens.

```
type Error = String
data Token = Plus | Minus | Mult | Div | Lp | Rp 
           | Var | Const | Whitespace deriving (Show, Eq)

tokenTable = [('+', Plus), ('-', Minus), ('*', Mult), ('/', Div), ('(', Lp), (')', Rp)]

tokenize :: String -> Either Error [Token]
tokenize "" = Right []
tokenize (x:xs) = case lookup x tokenTable of
  Just t -> fmap (t:) (tokenize xs)
  Nothing -> recognize x where
    recognize x 
      | isAlpha x = fmap (Var:) (tokenize xs)
      | isDigit x = fmap (Const:) (tokenize xs)
      | isSeparator x = fmap (Whitespace:) (tokenize xs)
      | otherwise = Left "Cannot determine lexeme"
```

However, this quickly becomes tedious. It already is, somehow, since we have to lift the list consing to `Either` using `fmap`. Imagine how you would implement indicating the location of the error? Going further essentialy becomes implementing a monad stack and reimplementing a parser combinator like `Parsec`. That's why it's often recomminded to use a combinator library directly, and also let it do the lexing.

And if you can't or don't want to use full `Parsec`, it's not too difficult to implement the [basic functionality](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/monparsing.pdf) by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse spaces in general. Here is a combination of your and phg's solutions:

```
import Data.Char

data Token = Plus | Minus | Mult | Div | Lp | Rp | Var | Digit | Undefined
  deriving Show

tokenMap :: String -> Token
tokenMap "+" = Plus
tokenMap "-" = Minus
tokenMap "*" = Mult
tokenMap "/" = Div
tokenMap "(" = Lp
tokenMap ")" = Rp
tokenMap [c]
  | isAlpha c = Var
  | isDigit c = Digit
tokenMap _ = Undefined

classify :: String -> [Token]
classify = map tokenMap . words
```